# Damp patch in basement wall that is loose material when I touch

Tags: basement, foundation

I recently noticed a damp patch in one spot on the basement wall. About a couple of inches in diameter.

When I poked into it the material came off and now there is a hole. Not deep or all the way in the foundation. But I stopped there.

The rest of the basement is dry and I do not see anything suspicious but am worried. We bought this house and it's 60 years old. Pictures attached.
[image: Basement Hole]

Comment: The old plaster/mortar used by the previous owner to fill the hole has aged and fallen. If no water issue, plug it with a cement-type grout to avoid insects take shelter behind.

Answer (score 1):

That is the the paint that has swollen and blistered out.   It is due to dampness.

My guess is that during heavy rains that the area right by the foundation on that side of the house is taking some water - hence the sump exit in the picture.

I don't really see a huge concern.   Just a couple of things...

1. Make sure after the next few heavy rain to check this area in the basement.
2. Also each time go outside and make sure there is no standing water near the house.  (and make sure you have proper grading)
3. Match up the outside with the inside and make sure there is nothing odd happening here.   I have seen basement walls have "moisture" issues because home owner's kids leaving the bib on and the constant leak eventually gets inside...   Make sure there are hose connections, drains, whatever right above this point.

Note - there is absolutely nothing you can do about this save build an exterior barrier.   Given the height of it on the wall and the fact I don't see a crack attached it looks like a non-issue.